# Final title in iMovie is always "title text here"

Tags: imovie

At the end of my iMovie project, I have a still image and the title "thanks for watching!". When I preview the scene it is fine. When I render it to file or youtube, the final title is always "title text here". This seems like a bug. Is it known to have a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the bug is caused by changing the title font-size before confirming the text. I needed to delete the exiting title and insert a new one; change the text **and hit enter** before changing font size. Then it worked.